# how to improve my damaged relationship with boss

Tags: management, team, politics

[**background**]
I work in IT for a bank. I moved from another team in the same organization to my current team - When I joined ( 2 years back ) I figured my boss is very territorial about the location he works form and how to ensure critical work stays in his location even if it does not make sense for the business. I obviously didn't like this behavior and had brought this up with local management ( my boss's boss). Soon after that I saw my boss being very nice and politically correct on every interaction he has had with me. Since I ( and some prev employees) had reported similar behavior in the past my boss was under some kind of pressure to show things are improving and he tried to kill all symptoms that people have reported but his ways and intentions did not really change, behind the scenes he is very biased still.

[**issue**]
My relationship with my boss is now bitter sweet, on the face/phone is very nice to me and at the same time keeps me away from interesting work. He has been ignoring me from a long time now and has successfully cornered me into doing every non critical projects to keep my busy. He knows that I am a senior member in the team and have the skill to contribute in much more capacity. He does not engage me into major decisions and keep others, more junior team members, more informed of where we are heading and whats next. *'Divide and Rule'.* to get direct attention from junior members in my location.

This makes me look small in front of everybody and I have noticed as a result of this other junior members in the team don't respect me and have developed some sort of understanding that I am not important.

Sucking it up for so long now this has really ruined my self esteem and enthusiasm. I don't just want to simply quit ,there has to be a way for me to overcome this. I am frustrated now please help!!

**edit#1** I really want to help my situation here and somehow make my boss understand that my intention was to provide constructive feedback and help team from other locations bond and be like ONE team. I don't know how to go about it , specially when I am getting all this treatment very silently. I could go speak to the same person ( next level up) I reported the issue to last time - but that didn't seem do me any good to me personally but others , plus it backfired me.

**edit#2** I would like to speak to HR about this but I don't know how to explain my exact situation since I have no proof for the treatment I am receiving. My boss can very easily justify his actions and make it look like there is no problem anywhere and work is equally distributed.

Comment: Hey dc, and welcome to [workplace.se]! I'm a bit unclear on what you're asking right now. You went over your boss' head to get him in trouble, and now he resents you for it. What do you want to do about this? You want to know how to apologize to your boss to get back on his good side? How to get more interesting work within an organization despite having your boss resenting you? As-is, this question is more about asking us what you should do than about explaining what the situation is and what type of help you are looking for. If you could clarify with an [edit] you will get better answers.

Comment: hello jmac thanks for your suggestions , I have updated my post. Hope that makes it little bit better

Comment: If your goal is to have your boss understand your point, I don't think you're going to have much success if your plan is to speak to HR or his boss. Are you totally unwilling to speak to your boss about this? I don't see how we can answer a question about how to improve your relationship with your boss if you are unwilling to actually speak to your boss...

Comment: I tried speaking to him telling him I am willing to do more and contribute in other initiatives we have. He did not show any interest and gave me more junk to work on. Have no problems speaking to my boss first ( as plan A) and to HR ( as plan B) but I am out of ideas

Comment: sounds like the relationship is very damaged, I'd work on the resume and give 110% in the meanwhile, try to build up at least good references from colleagues.

Comment: @dc069 So would you benefit from editing this question to instead be about how to repair your damaged relationship with your boss? That sounds like the best starting place for your issue to be honest. Any other action is likely to damage this relationship even further

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the people that I that know that do software development for banks (and financial institutions in general) complain about things like this. You are definitely not alone.

There are managers that like to pack their teams with 'their own people'.  This instinct is to ensure loyalty, which means it's more important for them to have 'loyal subjects' than it is necessarily to have the best results.  Anyone that 'goes around' is disloyal and is to be fired, punished, or isolated. It appears you're getting the latter of those treatments.

Good managers, in general, know how to work with what they've got.  What makes them good is a capacity to inspire, so they can get 'loyalty' by earning respect.  Someone like that can also live with a malcontent, if someone goes around to complain they don't take it personally.  In software development in particular, there is a saying about 'herding cats'.

Financial institutions, public sector agencies, and similar organizations tend to be 'conservative' - they hire on credentials, they promote by seniority, they don't like people rocking the boat, and they're picky about punctuality, dress, and decorum. It would appear you're a bad fit.  You may as well keep an eye out for other opportunities - preferably not in organizations that stifle initiative.

Your boss isn't listening, and HR won't be any improvement.  Talking to either of them will make things worse.

**Evaluating Your Situation**

Imagine a scenario in which your manager sliced off the entire team and launched your group as a startup in some clapped out warehouse.  If he, and your team, were directly responsible for customer satisfaction and product performance, would your business survive and prosper? If the answer is no, then you don't belong in that group. Period.  If you can't migrate to another part of the company, move to another company.

Comment: this organization does not stifle initiative but my immediate management seems to be of this nature. Most of them have been promoted to senior posts pre mature due to tons of fat cheque bosses leaving the firm in recent past.The new bosses I feel  are not very mature and with the newly acquired authority introducing more ass-kissing culture    ... power does not corrupt man but its man that corrupts power.

Comment: @dc069 - While your 'overall organization' may not do so, you're stuck with people that are. If you can't get out from under them in the organization you're in, you'll have to find a new employer.